# Trying to get getView().getTitle() to work

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I was first using only `getTitle()` for this but then found you need to use `getView()` as well. So i did but I stil can't get it to work.

FYI This is the error :
`Cannot resolve method 'getView' in 'Inventory'`

I tried changing `getInventory()` for `InventoryView()` but still the same error but also the `Cannot resolve method 'InventoryView' in 'Chest'` error so this means I cant get the inventory view from a block?

```
@EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Action a = e.getAction();
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        ItemStack hand = e.getItem();
        Block clicked = e.getClickedBlock();

        if (a != Action.PHYSICAL) {
            assert clicked != null;
            if(clicked.getType() == Material.CHEST){
                hand.getType();
                Chest chest = (Chest) clicked.getState();
                Inventory inv = chest.getInventory();
                if(inv.getView().getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Test")) {
                    p.sendMessage("Event triggered");
                    e.setCancelled(true);

                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to detect the name of a chest so i can open a gui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out after searching on around 100 sites I found a solution that works, I don't know if it's the best solution but good for me.

I changed the whole event to use `InventoryOpenEvent` insted of `PlayerInteractEvent`.

Here is the full code :

```
@EventHandler
    public void onInventoryOpen(InventoryOpenEvent e) {
        Player player = (Player) e.getPlayer();
        if (e.getView().getTitle().equals("Test")) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
            player.sendMessage("Succesfull");
        }
    }
```

Here is the code stripped down :

```
@EventHandler
    public void onInventoryOpen(InventoryOpenEvent e) {
        if (e.getView().getTitle().equals("Test")) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
```